# How to resolve with sbt Resolver maven2 repositories

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.3

How to resolve with sbt Resolver http://www.sarxos.pl/repo/maven2

I tryed

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.sarxos" % "webcam-capture-driver-ipcam" % "0.3.10-RC7"
resolvers += Resolver.url("SarXos Repository", url("http://www.sarxos.pl/repo/maven2"))
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Looks good, what message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see from the [documentations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html), the syntax should be:

```
resolvers += "SarXos Repository" at "http://www.sarxos.pl/repo/maven2"
```